# Friends List in Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-iframe, facebook-fbml

I am recently started my facebook app. I am using the new facebook api for PHP. I need to display the friends with their name and profile picture.More over I need to select the friends and i need to send a private message to them.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are not familiar with using php sdk, try the javascript sdk to get started it's easy to implement.

This link has documentation about the methods that you might need.

***http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/***

Comment: Try clicking on the methods in the above mentioned link, there are samples of usage.

Answer (score 1):

hey dude for that you have to use facebook API.

Answer (score 0):

U have an option of multi-friend-selector in FBJS for this type of usage(showing friends list and sending message)... u can use that... It looks fine, quit simple and efficient one.. Please refer the following link for brief explanation,

[Click me, i will show you briefly, :)](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/request-form/)

[Click me too for brief explanation.. :)](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/multi-friend-selector/)

if you have any other clarification please post in forum.. i will help you on this... :)